# hang on NtQuerySystemInformation in WinXPx32 but works fine in Win7x64

Tags: c#, winapi, filehandle

I have a class that will let me close process handles in a given process. I have the fundamentals down, and it works flawlessly in Win7 x64, but when I run it in WinXP x86, it hangs and I can't understand why. I feel like I am missing something fairly obvious, here.

```
    public static List<handleFinder.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION>
    GetHandles(Process process = null, string IN_strObjectTypeName = null, string IN_strObjectName = null)
    {
        int nLength = 0;
        int nHandleInfoSize = 0x10000;
        IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nHandleInfoSize);
        uint nStatus;

        while ((nStatus = handleFinder.NtQuerySystemInformation(CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, ipHandlePointer,nHandleInfoSize, ref nLength)) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
        {
            nHandleInfoSize = nLength;
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipHandlePointer);
            ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
        }

        byte[] baTemp = new byte[nLength];
        Marshal.Copy(ipHandlePointer, baTemp, 0, nLength);

        long lHandleCount = 0;
        if (Is64Bits())
        {
            lHandleCount = Marshal.ReadInt64(ipHandlePointer);
            ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandlePointer.ToInt64() + 8);
        }
        else
        {
            lHandleCount = Marshal.ReadInt32(ipHandlePointer);
            ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandlePointer.ToInt32() + 4);
        }

        handleFinder.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION shHandle;
        List<handleFinder.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION> lstHandles = new List<handleFinder.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION>();

        for (long lIndex = 0; lIndex < lHandleCount; lIndex++)
        {
            shHandle = new handleFinder.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION();
            if (Is64Bits())
            {
                shHandle = (handleFinder.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipHandle, shHandle.GetType());
                ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandle.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(shHandle) + 8);
            }
            else
            {
                ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandle.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(shHandle));
                shHandle = (handleFinder.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipHandle, shHandle.GetType());
            }
            if (process != null)
            {
                if (shHandle.ProcessID != process.Id) continue;
            }

            string strObjectTypeName = "";
            if (IN_strObjectTypeName != null)
            {
                strObjectTypeName = getObjectTypeName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
                if (strObjectTypeName != IN_strObjectTypeName) continue;
            }

            string strObjectName = "";
            if (IN_strObjectName != null)
            {
                strObjectName = getObjectName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
                if (strObjectName != IN_strObjectName) continue;
            }
            lstHandles.Add(shHandle);

            string strObjectTypeName2 = getObjectTypeName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
            string strObjectName2 = getObjectName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
            Console.WriteLine("{0}   {1}   {2}", shHandle.ProcessID, strObjectTypeName2, strObjectName2);

        }
        return lstHandles;
    }

    public static bool Is64Bits()
    {
        return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) == 8 ? true : false;
    }
}

public class HandleKiller
{
    public static void doMurderHandle()
    {
        String ProcessName = "xboxstat";

        try
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName)[0];
            var handles = Win32Processes.GetHandles(process, "File");
            if (handles.Count == 0) throw new System.ArgumentException("No handles found");
            foreach (var handle in handles)
            {
                IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                if (!handleFinder.DuplicateHandle(Process.GetProcessById(handle.ProcessID).Handle, handle.Handle, handleFinder.GetCurrentProcess(), out ipHandle, 0, false, handleFinder.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE))
                    Console.WriteLine("DuplicateHandle() failed, error = {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                Console.WriteLine("Handle Killed!");
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process name '{0}' is not currently running", ProcessName);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Handle '{0}' was not found in the process '{1}'", "", ProcessName);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `NtQuerySystemInformation` that's hanging, and not something else like `NtQueryObject`?

Comment: Is all of that code necessary to produce the hang?  Can you cut it down to just the essentials?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about removing the extra code, I am having a hard time figuring out whether it is the NtQueryObject or the NtQuerySystemInformation. When I step through it after a breakpoint, the loops go fine in WinXP, but if I try to step through it too quickly I get an error "Can not perform action because process is running."

Comment: @user2303420: The one thing I know is that if you try to call `NtQueryObject` to e.g. get the name of the "wrong" object (typically, certain named pipes in the system), the entire system can hang. There is *no way* to avoid this deadlock (and *only* this deadlock) without using kernel-mode code. I've never heard of `NtQuerySystemInformation` hanging though. See this for more info: http://forum.sysinternals.com/handle-name-help-ntqueryobject_topic14435.html

Comment: I have looked at that thread because that was my first thought... but because it pulls back everything just fine in Win7, I am inclined to lean towards something else as the root cause. NtQueryObject is just fine there. I will try to continue debugging.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the deadlock when encountering a synchronous named pipe with a pending wait operation, call CreateFileMapping() on the duplicated handle.

If GetLastError() returns 193 (ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT) then the handle is not a file handle and you should skip the query for the filename.

Unlike every other type of call to test for a named pipe, CreateFileMapping() doesn't deadlock in the kernel.

ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT -- ZwCreateSection probably returns STATUS_INVALID_FILE_FOR_SECTION which maps to that user error code.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566428(v=vs.85).aspx
also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113996

Comment: Old post, but I was having the same issue with registry keys and your answer helped me to fix it. I used RegNotifyChangeKeyValue with a dummy event

Comment: The Microsoft Support link is dead.  Here is an alternative link: https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/113996